# Looping over database connections

Tags: mysql, r

I have twelve MySQL database connections created using:

```r
mydb1 = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password=password, dbname='db',host='domain')
mydb2...  
mydb3...  
...
mydb12...
```

I have a script where I want to execute the same query on all 12 databases and loop through them.  How do I pass the `dbConnect` objects successfully to a `dbSendQuery`?

```r
items <- ls()[grep("mydb",ls())]
query <- dbSendQuery(items[1], "SELECT * FROM table")
```

gives me the error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’ for signature
>   ‘"character", "character"’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the textual representation of a connection object to the database functions. Your call is analogous to `dbSendQuery("mydb1", "select * from table")`, which I'm guessing you would not have typed in literally.

Ultimately you want to deal with a `list` of connections, which you can form manually with

```
conns <- list(mydb1, mydb2, ...)
```

but if that is difficult or you want to be more programmatic about it, try

```
conns <- lapply(ls()[grep("mydb",ls())], get)
```

and then

```
results <- lapply(conns, function(con) dbSendQuery(con, "select * from ..."))
```

Comment: So after trying this

    `items <- list(mydb1,mydb2,mydb3,mydb4,mydb5,mydb6,mydb7,mydb8,mydb9,mydb10,mydb11,mydb12)
    result1 <- dbSendQuery(items[1], "SELECT...`

I get Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’ for signature ‘"list", "character"’ . Is there something in your last statement that you're doing that I'm missing?

Comment: Please read the whole answer, I never suggested your `result1 <- ...` command.

Comment: r2evans I did read the whole answer and where I'm confused is how your `results <-` line differs from my `result1 <-` line.  R is obviously treating the data types differently across these two seemingly identical operations and this is where I'm needing assistance.

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you used double-brackets for indexing? Take a look at `items[1]` and then `items[[1]]` and see the difference. (See [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).)

Comment: If you want to do the same thing across multiple otherwise-identical objects, I urge you to consider using `lapply` (or a related vectorizing function). What's your reason for `lapply`-aversion, if I may ask?

Comment: I'm averse to the lapply function primarily because of it's strange behaviours that I see when compared to using the for loops that I am used to from other programming languages.  I know there's performance loss, but it's so negligible in my usage that for() is a much more straightforward command.

Comment: Are you able to explain to me why the double brackets are used to index a single-dimension list of connections?  I think I understand the concept, but as you can probably tell, I'm not the strongest R programmer yet.

Comment: (For brackets, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541269/difficulty-in-understanding-the-difference-between-double-and-single-bracket-sub, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777567/is-there-a-logical-way-to-think-about-list-indexing.) `for` versus `lapply` is no longer about speed (it's improved in last few years), it's mostly (to me) about code flow and methodology. To me, it is very simple to process a list of identically-structured results.